# ng-show not working in custom directive using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here my problem is, i want to show and hide textbox based on the json parameter, 
here i m getting json value (true, false ) but ng-show not working while bind the values 
Thanks for your help

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

    app.directive('telBasictext1', ['$http', 'telngshowservice', function($http, telngshowservice) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          placeHold: '@',
          checkId: '@',
          className: '@',
          ngmaxLength: '@',
          ngminLength: '@',
          lblvalue: '@',
          textboxSize: '@',
          lblSize: '@',
          validate: '@',
          ngShow: '@',
          textboxtype: '@',
          getString: '@',
          position: '@',
          labelPosition: '@',
          textboxPosition: '@',
          canShow: '@',
          showorhide: '@',
        },
        template: '<div   id="{{ checkId }}" class="form-group" ng-show="true"  > ' +
          '<label size="lblSize"  class="col-sm-{{ labelPosition }} control-label" id="textboxchanges">   Test </label>' +
          '<div class="col-sm-{{ textboxPosition }}"> <input type="{{ textboxtype }}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{ placeHold }}"  id="{{checkId}}"   class="{{className}}"  minlength="{{ ngminLength }}"  maxlength="{{ ngmaxLength }}"  size="{{ textboxSize }}"           ng-required="{{ validate }}" ></div></div>',

        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {



          var ngshow = iAttrs.canShow;
          var ngsplitValues = ngshow.split(",");
          var nglanguage = ngsplitValues[0]; // Language EN or Fr
          var nglabelName = ngsplitValues[1]; // Label Name
          var ngmoduleName = ngsplitValues[2]; // Module Name (global or local)

          telngshowservice.getdata(ngmoduleName).success(function(data) {

            scope.showorhide = data[nglabelName];
            console.log(scope.showorhide)


          })


        }
      };
    }]);



    app.factory('telngshowservice', ['$http', function($http) {
      var dataFactory = {};
      var lang = window.localStorage.language;
      dataFactory.getdata = function(moduleName) {

        if (moduleName == 'common') {

          return $http.get(labeli18nPath + '/translation_' + lang + '.json');
        } else {


          return $http.get('OPlayout.json');
        }
      };
      return dataFactory;
    }]);
```

Please check  below Url

http://plnkr.co/edit/J201Y11ojOz2mTTeP524?p=preview

Comment: please provide some examples to be able to help you

Comment: please check this link  http://plnkr.co/edit/J201Y11ojOz2mTTeP524?p=preview

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defined `hideorshow` in your isolated scope with text binding (@). Note: with text binding, two-way data binding wont work :)

Remove this and it'll just work (or use another scope variable)

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/h3MrWQjopbqzYa0Y5pOT

Comment: Thanks Lamisti, Working Fine

Comment: Lamisti but its not working in angularJs version 1.35 (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js)

Comment: 1st please remove your downvote and provide a plunker where it's not working, since it's working for me

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/h3MrWQjopbqzYa0Y5pOT?p=preview    just change the angularJs this ((https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js) version

Comment: Lamisti i got answer , the reason is  {
    "pSearchPatient": false,
    "pAddressNo" : true,
    "pBuilding": true
} i  am using booleans instead of strings now its working fine, thanks